# Using orderbychild.equalTo() can't retrieve firebase data

Tags: android, firebase

this is login :                                     this is add food page:
[image: this is login]            [image: this is add food page]

code:
[image: code]

my firebase rules:
[image: my firebase rules]

my firebase data:
[image: my firebase data]

Here is my FoodInfo code:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties

public class FoodInfo {

public String foodname, foodprice, fooddesc, imageUrl, storename;

public FoodInfo(){

}




public FoodInfo(String foodname, String foodprice, String fooddesc, String imageUrl, String storename ) {
    this.foodname = foodname;
    this.foodprice = foodprice;
    this.fooddesc = fooddesc;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.storename = storename;


}

public String getFoodname() {
    return foodname;
}

public String getFoodprice() {
    return foodprice;
}

public String getFooddesc() {
    return fooddesc;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public String getStorename() {
    return storename;
}

public void setFoodname(String foodname) {
    this.foodname = foodname;
}

public void setFoodprice(String foodprice) {
    this.foodprice = foodprice;
}

public void setFooddesc(String fooddesc) {
    this.fooddesc = fooddesc;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}
}
```

The textview in add food page will get the data from "enter your email" editext, I'm using

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String StoreName = intent.getStringExtra ("Storename");
```

Now my problem is when I click on the menu button (which is the add food page), I want it to display only data that has the same child with textview (in add food page there). So I'm using orderbychild, is it correct?

And I put Storename inside equalTo() but that not working.
And every time I click on menu button, it shows "Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "storename"' at FoodInfo to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance"

Comment: actually now all the sellers are sharing the same recycleview, so when click on the menu  button, i want it only display the data that added by this seller, that's why i pass the seller name to add food page and store in FoodInfo firebase

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order by child should be working fine. You can check by -

```
    Log.i("Value", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
```

If your intent is working right i.e. it should be passing storename as "Gg" in the query. You will receive the required data.

So, the problem can be in the model (FoodInfo.class). So share the model (FoodInfo.class)..

Comment: i already added FoodInfo.class codes

Comment: what result this is giving ?

             Log.i("Value", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

Comment: where should i put this code?

Comment: query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Value  " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      
                Log.i("Value", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

            }

and comment this line
mfoodInfo.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(FoodInfo.class));

Comment: sry, i new in android studio, in this code,                                       
Toast.makeText(this, "Value " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                                 .toString need to put () right, after put () what should i put inside()

Comment: Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("storename").equalTo(StoreName);
        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                mfoodinfo.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(FoodInfo.class));
                Toast.makeText(this, "Value " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("Value", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
              
            }

Comment: whats the output you are getting?

Comment: Cannot reslove method 'makeText(anonyomous com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListner,java.lang,string,int )

Comment: would you mind give me your emai addressl? since I can't get any notification if I didn't open stack overflow

Comment: i already email to you

Comment: add foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); onChildAdded after  mfoodinfo.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(FoodInfo.class)); and your problem will be solved

Comment: it works, tq for saving my life